# ASUS PN50 AMD RYZEN 5 4500U - Graphic Drivers

Tags: asus, gpu

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on my Asus ASUS PN50 AMD RYZEN 5 4500U with integrated Radeon Vega 7 Graphics.

I have noticed the graphics drivers are not functioning properly - I can't adjust screen resolution.
On the ASUS website, I can only see the graphic drivers for Windows available to download. Are graphic drivers for Ubuntu available?

Answer (score 3):

To fix the brightness problem you need the 5.8 linux kernel.

You can install Ubuntu 20.10 that has this kernel, or upgrade the kernel of the 20.04.1 release by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge
```

Reboot after the kernel is installed. Brightness control should work.

You don't need any additional drivers.

Comment: Thanks. That helped to get my PN50 with Ryzen 4500u to qork @ 3840x2160. :)

Comment: great its worked for me hp zhan amd